# ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException when not trying to change the foreign key?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

In the following code, I don't believe I am changing the foreign key, but I could be wrong.  When I run it, I get the exception:

> ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException

Here is the code:

```
UsersModule um = dc.UsersModules.Where(x => x.UserId == IdParam).FirstOrDefault();
int oldModuleId = um.ModuleId;
string oldModule = um.Module.ModuleName;
```

The error is thrown on the line:

```
string oldModule = um.Module.ModuleName
```

I don't know why I am getting this error because I am just trying to store the value of `ModuleName` into string `oldModule`, not change `um.Module.ModuleName`

Comment: Try to look into the genereted code files behind the manifest file .dbml. Assumed that you used the designer to add the L2S classes. Try to see if there is exception throwing in the getters.

Comment: I looked and it is thrown in the geter.

Comment: Im lost. I tried to reproduce this without luck. I craeted two tables, one with a foreign key to the other. Say B -> A. Then i got a item from B and tried accessing the A object through the B ojebct and reading As name (non key). Like this B b = dc.Bs.First(); string s = b.A.Name; And it worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ works based on relational entities. So, whenever you need to set/read a foreign key value, it must be done by setting/reading the foreign entity instelad. Which means that shortcuts such as “Module.ModuleName” does not work very well.

Comment: I think the above code should work. Thats one of the cool features in Linq to Sql. And he is not trying to change anything, just read values.

Comment: I just fixed my answer. Set or Read doesnt matter.

Comment: ok so that explains the error while getting, but ModuleName is not a foreign key.  Can you explain what the foreign entity is?

Comment: Still not sure why the reading should fail. I just tried testing it and it worked.

Comment: I know that if you make a reading like this: um.Module, you can no longer change the value of um.ModuleId. But here, its only reading.